# Exists $C$ constant: $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}\leq\{ ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}}+||f'||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \}, \forall f\in S(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative, schwartz-space

> Show that there exists $C$ constatant such that $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}\leq\{ ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}}+||f'||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \}, \forall f\in S(\mathbb{R})$.

This is a question in my homework of PDE but I'm unable to to progress beyond a certain point.

**MY ATTEMPT** (following the professor's hint)

(Fourier inversion)
$$
|f(x)|=\left| \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{i \langle x,\xi\rangle}\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi \right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\left|\hat{f}(\xi)\right|d\xi = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}\left|\hat{f}(\xi)(1+i\xi)\right|\frac{1}{(1+\xi^2)^{1/2}}d\xi\leq
$$
(Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)
$$
\leq  \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\left|\hat{f}(\xi)(1+i\xi)\right|^2d\xi\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{(1+\xi^2)}d\xi\right)^{1/2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\pi}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\left|\hat{f}(\xi)(1+i\xi)\right|^2d\xi\right)^{1/2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\pi} ||\hat{f}(\xi)(1+i\xi)||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}
$$
from this point I'm unable to work. I don't know how to make the $f$ and $f'$ come on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\lVert\widehat{f}(\xi)(1+i\xi)\rVert_2\leqslant \lVert \widehat f\rVert_2+
\lVert \xi \cdot \widehat{f(\cdot)}\rVert_2.$$
To conclude, use Plancherel's identity and integrating by part in the definition of the Fourier transform we may decuce a link between $\xi \cdot \widehat{f}$ and the Fourier transform of $f'$.

Comment: I think you mean either $\xi \cdot \widehat{f(\cdot)}$ or $\widehat{f'}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Indeed. Fixed now, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your first displayed equation: this should be $\xi\int_{\mathbb R} f(t)e^{i\xi t}dt$. You can integrate by part in the last displayed equation.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo [UPDATE], thank you. Is not the fist time that you help me. I understand the inequality but I can not see the link beteween $\xi\cdot \hat{f}$ and $\hat{f'}$. What I see is this:
$$
\xi\cdot\hat{f}=\xi\left\{\int_\mathbb{R}[\hat{f}(\xi)]e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle} dx\right\}
$$
and
$$
\hat{f'(\xi)}=\int_\mathbb{R}f'(x)e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle} dx
$$

Comment: Can you see if that is ok? Integrating by part the last equation:
calling: $u=e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle}$ and $dv=f'(x)$
$$
\hat{f'}(\xi)=f(x)\cdot e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle}-\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle}dx=f(x)e^{-i\langle x, \xi \rangle}-\hat{f}(\xi)
$$

Comment: The term $f(x)\cdot e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle}$ should be $[f(x)\cdot e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle}]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, which is $0$. In the integral, you forgot the derivative with respect to $x$ of $e^{-ix\xi}$. Notice that there is no need to use $\langle, \rangle$ because we work with functions defined on the real line.

Comment: Why $[f(x)\cdot e^{-ix\xi}]^\infty_{-\infty}=0$ and if $f(x)=e^x$?

Comment: This because $f$ belongs to the Schwaz space.