# Estimation of the $L^{\infty}$ norm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

In one of the questions of my PDE course we are asked to prove that if $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$, where $S$ denotes the Schwartz space then there is a $C>0$ such that:

$||f||_{L^\infty} \leq C\{||f||_{L^2} +||f'||_{L^2}\}$

I started by estimating:

$|f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}|(1+i\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)|(1+\xi^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}d\xi$

My professor advised to use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but I don't see that might help in this case. I also thought about using the Parseval's theorem. Hoping someone might help pme by shedding some light on the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exists $C$ constant: $||f||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})}\leq\{ ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}}+||f'||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \}, \forall f\in S(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799075/exists-c-constant-f-l-infty-mathbbr-leq-f-l2-mathbbr)

Comment: In some way it does, but I didn't understand the part about the integration by parts that arises when  evaluating the fourier transform of the derivative. I'll try to write it down calmly and see if I get any insights